# Creating a function to write to a file

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, definition

I have just recently started coding for my game development class and have run into a problem. Part of the homework was to make a function that allows us to write to a file via user input. I've gotten everything down I believe except I can't actually write to the file? The function I'm talking about is: def write_file() and Option 9 on the list. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
enter = 0
start = 0
Roger = ()
read = open("read.txt", "r")
x = read.read()
read1 = open("read.txt", "w")



def read_file(read):
    return open(read)

def write_file(read1):
    read1 = open("read.txt", "w")
    read1.write(input())
    read1.close()
    return read1

def update_score(scores, person, amount):
    for score in scores:
        if score[0].lower() == person.lower():
            score[1] += amount
    return scores

def update_score1(scores, person, amount):
    for score in scores:
        if score[0].lower() == person.lower():
            score[1] -= amount
    return scores

def addition(num1):
    return num1 + num1

def square(num):
    print("I'm in square")
    return num * num

def display(message):
    """Display game instuctions"""
    print(message)

def instructions():
    """Display game instuctions"""
    print("Welcome to the world's greatest game")


def main():
    str1 = ["Roger", 3456]
    str2 = ["Justin", 2320]
    str3 = ["Beth", 1422]
    instructions()
    scores = [str1, str2, str3]

    start = input("Would you like to view the high score options? y/n ")
    if start == "y":
        print("""\
        Hello! Welcome to the high scores!
        Here are the current high score leaders!:
        """)
        print(scores)
        print("""\n\
        0 - Sort high scores
        1 - Add high score
        2 - Reverse the order
        3 - Remove a score
        4 - Square a number
        5 - Add 2 numbers together
        6 - Add to a score
        7 - Subtract from a score
        8 - Read a file
        9 - Write to a file
        """)
        option = int(input("Please enter your selection "))
        while option < 8:
            print(scores)            
            if option == 0:
                scores.sort()
                print("These are the scores sorted alphabetically")
                print(scores)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 1:
                print(scores)
                print("Please enter your name and score; After entering your name, hit the return key and enter your score")
                name = input()
                score = int(input())
                entry = (name,score)
                scores.append(entry)
                print(scores)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 2:
                print(scores)
                scores.reverse()
                print("\nHere are the scores reversed")
                print(scores)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 3:
                print(scores)
                print("Please enter the high score you would like to remove. After typing the name, hit the return key and enter the score")
                name1 = input()
                score1 = int(input())
                remove = (name1,score1)
                scores.remove(remove)
                print(scores)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 4:
                val = int(input("Give me a number to square"))
                sqd = square(val)
                print(sqd)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 5:
                val0 = int(input("Give me one number"))
                val1 = int(input("Give me another number"))
                addi = (val0 + val1)
                print(addi)
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 6:
                print(scores)
                sc0 = input("Please enter player whose score you would like to increase. ")
                sc1 = int(input("Please enter the amount would would like to add to their score. "))
                scores = update_score(scores, sc0, sc1)
                print(scores)                          
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
            elif option == 7:
                sc2 = input("Please enter player whose score you would like to decrease. ")
                sc3 = int(input("Please enter the amount you would like to subtract from their score. "))
                scores = update_score1(scores, sc2, sc3)
                print(scores)
        while option <= 9:
            if option == 8:
                print(read.readlines())
                read.close()
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection "))                
            if option == 9:
                print(read.readlines())

                print(read.readlines())
                read1.close()
                option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection "))      



main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be taking an arg, simply open the file and write, if you are just storing the output there is no need to return:

```
def write_file():
    inp = input("Enter filename to save data to:")
    with open(inp, "w") as f:
         f.write(input("Enter data to save:"))
```

You also use  `return open(read)` which looks like you are trying to call `open` on the file object you opened at the start of the code.

In your main loop you keep calling  `read.readlines()` which will not work, a file object returns its own iterator which is exhausted after a single call to `readlines` and certainly won't work when you have closed the file, you would have to reopen each time, use `read.seek(0)` or store the first call to readlines in a variable and then use that. I suggest you don't keep using the same variables everywhere as it makes your code confusing and will lead to problems.

Comment: I changed the writing function around and now it works (thanks)! Now I can't figure out the reading part. I scratched the return open(read) part. Would it be almost similar to the writing function's code?

Comment: Use with again to open like in my code  and just return f.readlines() if you want a list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for `write_file` looks fine but there is nowhere in your program that you're actually calling the `write_file` function. Maybe you should find where you want to call that first.